# How I can get authentication token from SharePoint Online and create event in Outlook 365 calendar without navigating to login window?

Tags: sharepoint-online, office-365, calendar

I have to create an calendar event in Outlook 365 from SharePoint Online. I know that I can achieve this using `https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/me/events` call in Microsoft Graph API.

The only problem I am facing is in authentication. Can I use the token from SharePoint Online and authenticate Outlook 365 and create an event there? If yes, then how can I get that token and use that for authenticating outlook 365 for Microsoft Graph API?

I don't want any more sign in window to authenticate.

Any suggestions are most welcome.

Comment: Have you been able to figure out any work around for this problem?

Comment: I actually ended up using Sign-In window to get the authentication token.

Answer (score 0):

@Aakash Maurya,

I think it's possible to avoid prompting login window again. You can take a reference of OAuth 2.0 On-Behalf-Of flow:

- https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-on-behalf-of-flow

[image]

And another possible solution is to use refresh token:

Although access token only against one resource, its refresh token is valid for all permissions that your client has already received consent for - thus, a refresh token issued on a request for scope=mail.read can be used to request a new access token for scope=api://contoso.com/api/UseResource.

- [Refresh the access token](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow#refresh-the-access-token)

BR